# Php file not found on Windows hosting

Tags: php, html, windows-hosting

Windows hosting on godaddy.

I have 4 pages, main page is `Index.html` and the rest 3 are `.php` pages.

When I upload the `Index.php` file the site doesn't work, but when I and replace the `Index.php` file with `Index.html`, The site works perfectly.

What is the problem with the `Index.php` file?

Comment: Show us a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

php is extention start with

```
<?php
```

just make new file as sample.php and type this code as sample than test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and check is it working or not if its working so you are doing wrong with your pages